# Unable to use sync with typed racket

Tags: scheme, racket, typed-racket

Hi I'm learning how to use logging facilities provided by racket. I wrote the following piece of code to get the hang of how things are working.

```
#lang racket

(define list-logger (make-logger 'list-logger))

;;(: log-debug (String Symbol -> Void))
(define (log-debug message name)
  (log-message list-logger 'debug message name))

;;(: sum-a-list ((Listof Integer) (Integer Integer -> Integer) -> Integer))
(define (sum-a-list l operator)
  (begin (log-debug (format "Message ~a" l) 'sum-a-list)
         (cond [(empty? l) 0]
         [else (operator (first l) (sum-a-list (rest l) operator))])))

(define recevier (make-log-receiver list-logger 'debug))

;;(: main (-> Any))
(define (main)
  (begin (sum-a-list (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) +)
         ;; (: logger (-> Any)
         (define (logger)
           (let ([msg (sync recevier)])
             (match msg
               [(vector level m data x) (begin (printf "~a: ~a\n" level m)
                                               (logger))]
               [else #f ])))
         (logger)))
```

The code above compiles and works fine. The problem arises when I used typed racket instead of racket. For the same code (with type annotations and typed/racket) I get a type checker error.

```
;; code with typed racket and type annotations
#lang typed/racket

(define list-logger (make-logger 'list-logger))

(: log-debug (String Symbol -> Void))
(define (log-debug message name)
  (log-message list-logger 'debug message name))

(: sum-a-list ((Listof Integer) (Integer Integer -> Integer) -> Integer))
(define (sum-a-list l operator)
  (begin (log-debug (format "Message ~a" l) 'sum-a-list)
         (cond [(empty? l) 0]
         [else (operator (first l) (sum-a-list (rest l) operator))])))

(define recevier (make-log-receiver list-logger 'debug))

(: main (-> Any))
(define (main)
  (begin (sum-a-list (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) +)
         (: logger (-> Any))
         (define (logger)
           (let ([msg (sync recevier)])
             (match msg
               [(vector level m data x) (begin (printf "~a: ~a\n" level m)
                                               (logger))]
               [else #f ])))
         (logger)))

;; type checker error: Type Checker: untyped identifier sync imported from module <typed/racket> in: sync
```

I want to use typed racket to implement logging support in my project. I have no clue how to solve this error. Please help me out in solving this problem. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** `sync` is now supported in the current release of Typed Racket, as part of Racket version 6.0.

---

The `sync` function isn't supported natively yet in any release version of Typed Racket because event types are not supported. If you download a recent pre-release version of Racket (either from the [snapshot site](http://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/snapshots/) or [github](https://github.com/plt/racket)), you should get a version of Typed Racket that supports events and `sync`.

Caveat: the pre-release build is more likely to have bugs. Bug reports welcome!